# AJAX Form Submission Styling

Tags: css, ajax, forms, jquery

I am using Ajax with jQuery to submit a webform. When the webform submits a nice thank you message comes up. The message covers the form itself and will provide the user with information on what to do next etc. The issue is that the form can have several fields and when the user hits submit they see the form disappear but that is about it.

I added some JS that would kick the user to the top of the page (and see the thank you message at the top) but still there can be a lot of blank space where the form was.

The question I have is how would I go about having the form change from its starting state to display:none; while the confirmation message shows in its place.

Here is a copy of my code:

```
function jqsub() {

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
var $jform = $j('#ajaxform'); // form ID
var $jmessagebox = $j('#ajaxdiv'); // message box ID
var $jsuccessmessage = "<h3>Thank You For Your Submission!</h3>"; // success message in HTML format
var $jerrormessage = "<h3>Error - Please Try Again</h3>"; //error message in HTML format

$j.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $jform.attr('action'),
    data: $jform.serialize(), 
    success: function (msg) { 
                        if (msg.FormProcessV2Response.success) {
                        $jmessagebox.append($jsuccessmessage) 
                        $jmessagebox.fadeIn();
                        }
                        else {
                        $jmessagebox.append($jerrormessage) 
                        $jmessagebox.fadeIn();  
                        }    
                },
    error: function (msg) {
                        $jmessagebox.append($jerrormessage) 
                        $jmessagebox.fadeIn();
                },
     });
$j( 'html, body' ).animate( { scrollTop: 0 }, 0 );
}
```

Here is the page I am working with: http://ubhape2remodel.businesscatalyst.com/testform.html

One other note: If there is an error on the form what is a simple way to have the Error message go away and the form show again? (Basically swapping states back to where the form shows vs the message) Thanks again for your help!

Hope all of that makes sense.

I welcome any advice, ideas, and help.

Thanks!

Lynda

Comment: its showing correctly. after the successful submission of form it is showing the success message correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fade your form out slowly and then show the mesage:

```
$jform.fadeOut("slow", function(){
  $jmessagebox.fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: For me this is the best answer along with BraedenP's help with the ability for allowing the form to fade back in in event of an error. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can hide the elements using `.hide()`

Answer (score 0):

The ID of the form on your page is 'ajaxform' so the following should hide the form (using the $j object that you have defined above):

```
$j("#ajaxform").css("display","none");
```

May I also suggest putting the hiding/scrolling code inside the success callback function? If the form isn't submitted successfully, you don't want to tell your users it was, do you?

Edited to show bringing back the form after an error (where buttonID is the ID of the button in the messagebox:

```
$j("#buttonID").live("click",function(){
    $jmessagebox.fadeOut("slow", function(){
        $jform.fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by the hiding/scrolling code? When the form submits it will show the success. If there was an error that will show instead of the success message. But this brings up a question. The error code will show but the form will be gone. What is a simple way to have the Error message go away and the form show again? (Basically swapping states back to where the form shows vs the message) Thanks again for your help!

Comment: To do that, just put a delay after your $jmessagebox.fadeIn() function. So to create a 5-second delay before bringing the form back: $jmessagebox.fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut();$j("#ajaxform").fadeIn();

Comment: If you're going to be fading it back in, consider using $j("#ajaxform").fadeOut() or $j("#ajaxform").hide() instead of the above code, though. This will make sure you don't confuse the jQuery animation functions.

Comment: I used Edgar's method that he mentioned and it works great. What I would like is on error message the user will see the message then must click a button to go back to the form to re-submit. When I try to incorporate this into the "messagebox" part of the script I break the script. (I am using JS to show the form again) Any advice on how I can put that button in the messagebox and not break the script. Thanks!

Comment: It shouldn't cause a problem.. Just put a button in your message, assign it an ID of some sort, and then, since you liked Edgar's solution to the first part, I've added an edit to the post above to show how that could be done.

Comment: Thanks! It works beautifully! I realize now part of the issue I was running into was my lack of experience. I was receiving errors because I was using " not ' Thanks!

Comment: In Javascript, the type of quotation mark you use is irrelevant; both should work just fine. There must have been some other small error that was preventing it from doing what you intended. Glad it's working now :)

Comment: Dreamweaver kept giving me syntax errors when I used " vs '  but hey it works so I am happy =>

Answer (score 0):

Why not extracting the message from the form, and on success, first fading out the form, then fading in the message:

```
 if (success) {
     $('#formId').fadeOut('fast', function(){
          $('#messageId').fadeIn('fast');
     });
 }
```

To make'em happen one after the other (sequential) you have to provide a callback function for fadeOut.